# Different methods to access elements in a list

Tags: r, list

I know this is a newbie question, but I am trying to understand the difference between the [[ ]] and $ in accessing elements in a list. Are there special cases where I have advantages to use one over the other?

I think to understand that you can use [[ to select any single element and the returned object will be determined by the type of the element, whereas [ returns a list object of the selected element or even a list with multiple elements. On the other hand when using $ to reference an element in a list the returned type is not a list but the actual value.

Is this korrect? Are there any occasions where I must use [[ ]] or $?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd benefit from reading [the list chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html) of "R for Data Science".

Basically, you can use `$` when the list elements have names:

```
mylist <- list(x = 1:3, y = 4:6)
names(mylist)
[1] "x" "y"

mylist$x
[1] 1 2 3
```

You can use `[[]]` for a named list as well as an unnamed list, if you like:

```
mylist[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

But you can't use `$` if the list elements are not named:

```
mylist <- list(1:3, 4:6)
names(mylist)
NULL

mylist$x
NULL

mylist[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thank you neilfws, I started to read this resourse yesterday :)

Answer (score 1):

from the R language definiton (https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing):

> The form using $ applies to recursive objects such as lists and
>   pairlists. It allows only a literal character string or a symbol as
>   the index. That is, the index is not computable: for cases where you
>   need to evaluate an expression to find the index, use x[[expr]].

For example:

```
my.list = list("a"=1 , "b"=2)
my.index = "b"
#this works
my.list[[my.index]]    
# this doesn't    
my.list$my.index
```

Comment: Thank you David, but I have dificulties to understand what it means that the index is not computable ...

Comment: ok, see my edit.